# Pointer to JNA Structure not resolved correctly

Tags: java, struct, jna

I am currently using JNA on a Linux device that is used for m2m purposes and comes with a C Library that includes the following code:

```c
typedef struct _INET_MODULE_CONFIG{
       unsigned char  wBearer;                   
       void* wBearerParameters;
       void  (*inet_action)( INET_Events * );
    }INET_MODULE_CONFIG;

    typedef struct _GPRS_CONFIG{
       unsigned char gprsUser[ 20];             
       unsigned char gprsPass[ 20];             
       unsigned char gprsDNS1[ 20];             
       unsigned char gprsDNS2[ 20];             
       unsigned char gprsAPN [ 20];            
    }GPRS_CONFIG;

    typedef struct _GPRS_ENHANCED_CONFIG{
       unsigned char gprsUser[ USER_SIZE];        
       unsigned char gprsPass[ PWD_SIZE];         
       unsigned char gprsDNS1[ IP_SIZE];      
       unsigned char gprsDNS2[ IP_SIZE];      
       unsigned char gprsAPN [ APN_SIZE];     
    }GPRS_ENHANCED_CONFIG;
```

The `wBearerParameter` points to one of the GPRS Structs, and `wBearer` decides to which, by using a constant.

To map this to Java I use this:

```java
public class INET_MODULE_CONFIG extends Structure implements Structure.ByReference
{
    public byte wBearer;
    public Pointer wBearerParameters;
    public inet_event_handler inet_action;
}
    
public class GPRS_CONFIG extends Structure implements Structure.ByReference
{       
    public byte[] gprsUser;
    public byte[] gprsPass;
    public byte[] gprsDNS1;
    public byte[] gprsDNS2;
    public byte[] gprsAPN;
}
    
public class GPRS_ENHANCED_CONFIG extends Structure implements Structure.ByReference
{
    public byte[] gprsUser;
    public byte[] gprsPass;
    public byte[] gprsDNS1;
    public byte[] gprsDNS2;
    public byte[] gprsAPN;
}
```

And then this to use it:

```
grsKonfig.gprsUser = new byte[20];
gprsKonfig.gprsPass = new byte[20];
gprsKonfig.gprsAPN = new byte[20];
gprsKonfig.gprsDNS1 = new byte[20];
gprsKonfig.gprsDNS2 = new byte[20];
        
gprsKonfig.gprsUser[0] = 't';
gprsKonfig.gprsUser[1] = '-';
gprsKonfig.gprsUser[2] = 'm';
gprsKonfig.gprsUser[3] = 'o';
gprsKonfig.gprsUser[4] = 'b';
gprsKonfig.gprsUser[5] = 'i';
gprsKonfig.gprsUser[6] = 'l';
gprsKonfig.gprsUser[7] = 'e';
for(int i = 8; i < 20; i++)
{
    gprsKonfig.gprsUser [i]= 0;
}

gprsKonfig.gprsPass[0] = 't';
gprsKonfig.gprsPass[1] = 'm';
for(int i = 2; i < 20; i++)
{
    prsKonfig.gprsPass [i]= 0;
}
        
gprsKonfig.gprsAPN[0] = 'i';
gprsKonfig.gprsAPN[1] = 'n';
gprsKonfig.gprsAPN[2] = 't';
gprsKonfig.gprsAPN[3] = 'e';
gprsKonfig.gprsAPN[4] = 'r';
gprsKonfig.gprsAPN[5] = 'n';
gprsKonfig.gprsAPN[6] = 'e';
gprsKonfig.gprsAPN[7] = 't';
gprsKonfig.gprsAPN[8] = '.';
gprsKonfig.gprsAPN[9] = 't';
gprsKonfig.gprsAPN[10] = 'e';
gprsKonfig.gprsAPN[11] = 'l';
gprsKonfig.gprsAPN[12] = 'e';
gprsKonfig.gprsAPN[13] = 'k';
gprsKonfig.gprsAPN[14] = 'o';
gprsKonfig.gprsAPN[15] = 'm';
for(int i = 16; i < 20; i++)
{
    gprsKonfig.gprsAPN [i]= 0;
}
        
gprsKonfig.gprsDNS1[0] = '8';
gprsKonfig.gprsDNS1[1] = '.';
gprsKonfig.gprsDNS1[2] = '8';
gprsKonfig.gprsDNS1[3] = '.';
gprsKonfig.gprsDNS1[4] = '8';
gprsKonfig.gprsDNS1[5] = '.';
gprsKonfig.gprsDNS1[6] = '8';
for(int i = 7; i < gprsKonfig.gprsDNS1.length; i++)
{
    gprsKonfig.gprsDNS1[i] = '0';
}
    
gprsKonfig.gprsDNS2[0] = '8';
gprsKonfig.gprsDNS2[1] = '.';
gprsKonfig.gprsDNS2[2] = '8';
gprsKonfig.gprsDNS2[3] = '.';
gprsKonfig.gprsDNS2[4] = '4';
gprsKonfig.gprsDNS2[5] = '.';
gprsKonfig.gprsDNS2[6] = '4';
for(int i = 8; i < gprsKonfig.gprsDNS2.length; i++)
{
    gprsKonfig.gprsDNS2[i] = '0';
}

inetKonfig.wBearer = InternetBibliothek.NORMAL_BEARER_GPRS;
inetKonfig.wBearerParameters = gprsKonfig.getPointer();
inetKonfig.inet_action = callback;
```

It compiles without an error. Sometimes the C Library tells me I have an error in my GPRS params, but in most cases not. However the DNS servers are not set correctly. In `/etc/resolv.conf` I now have `8.8.4.40000000000000internet.telekom` and `8.8.8.800000000000008.8.4.40000000000000internet.telekom`.
It looks like it does not know where the arrays end. Also I need the trailing 0 to go away, since my internet provider tells me to leave both DNS server empty (The ones I used above are just to see what stands in `/etc/resolv.conf`).

Comment: I can guess that problem in `gprsKonfig.getPointer()`, how it is defined?

Comment: It is a Method from the JNA Class Structure. In the docu is says: "Return a Pointer object to this structure.". I saw other people using it whenever they use a Pointer object.

Comment: I think it have problem because it doesn't know that each array should be 20 bites long. Maybe you need some annotations on your fields.

Comment: i made them 20 bytes long and filled it up with 0. Now i have `00000000000000000000internet.telekom` and `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000internet.telekom` in my `resolv.conf` so it is somewhat closer, since this is the apn with som 0, but still not correct.

Comment: Look like you filled it wrong. Can you edit your question and add that new code?

Comment: I just did. Also i used the google dns server to see whats writen in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: When you do `= '0' ` it should be `= 0`.

Comment: In fact arrays are filled with 0 by default, so you don't need those loops.

Comment: God, thats probably also why it didnt work last time i tried to fill it with 0. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Now be a good person and post answer:) I can't, I'm on mobile, and formating a code is pain :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you answered your own question with a [correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64208168), I want to add a bit more detail to it that may help you streamline your code.

JNA Structures must know their size when allocating native memory for them.  Therefore, arrays must be initialized with full size at the time of structure instantiation.  In your specific case, this means initializing the arrays like this:

```java
public class GPRS_CONFIG extends Structure {       
    public byte[] gprsUser = new byte[20];
    public byte[] gprsPass = new byte[20];
    public byte[] gprsDNS1 = new byte[20];
    public byte[] gprsDNS2 = new byte[20];
    public byte[] gprsAPN = new byte[20];
}

public class GPRS_ENHANCED_CONFIG extends Structure {
    public byte[] gprsUser = new byte[USER_SIZE];
    public byte[] gprsPass = new byte[PWD_SIZE];
    public byte[] gprsDNS1 = new byte[IP_SIZE];
    public byte[] gprsDNS2 = new byte[IP_SIZE];
    public byte[] gprsAPN = new byte[APN_SIZE];
}
```

I'll also note that there's no need to implement `ByReference` unless the struture is nested *by reference* (as a pointer) inside another structure.  If you do implement it, there's more code you'd need.

Another error in your code is implementation of null terminated strings. Null is an actual byte value of 0.  The character zero (`'0'`) is not the same, it is actually the byte value of 48.  You could use the character '\0' (which has the byte value 0) to accomplish this if necessary; however it's not usually needed.

If you are initializing a primitive byte arrays with `new byte[SIZE]`, the 0 values are already initialized in the array, so you don't need to do anything special to explicitly set them.

You might also find it eaiser to set the character values by using the `String` class `getBytes()` and then copying the values in the array over using `System.arraycopy()`.  For example:

```java
byte[] dnsBytes = "8.8.8.8".getBytes("ASCII");
System.arraycopy(dnsBytes, 0, gprsKonfig.gprsDNS1, 0, dnsBytes.length);
```

Answer (score 2):

Initialise it with the length of 20, and use 0 without '', as trailing.